# Convert each array element into seperate string

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Suppose, I have

```
var temp1TeamName = String()
var temp2TeamName = String()
var teamNameOnceArray = [[String]]()
```

Which I need to want

```
for i in 0..100 {
    if(i=0) {
        temp1TeamName = ((teamNameOnceArray[i] as AnyObject) as! String)
    }
    if(i=1) {
        temp2TeamName = ((teamNameOnceArray[i] as AnyObject) as! String)
    }
}
```

Basically I want to store the each element of the array into different String.

But in runtime it crashes. And the error is

`Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' 
    (0x10560c988) to 'NSString' (0x1036ba2a8).`

`Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' 
     (0x10560c988) to 'NSString' (0x1036ba2a8).`

Comment: What is the type of your array? Also why would you convert each element into a separate variable instead of maybe, converting into an array of String? I'm not sure but I think you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Why would you even want that? What's the purpose of array then if you're storing the data in 100 different variables?

Comment: Your “array” is actually an array of arrays of String, so drop one set of square braces. Also, this is exactly why we have arrays - unpacking them to 100 variables is unlikely to be the right way to do what you need.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to understand what you want to do if you added an example of the array so we can see what it contains.

Comment: This is an Array of an array of strings and you are just trying to convert an array to the string that is the issue.